# Get newest ListItems from a List

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to get *n* newest list items or items created within a year or so from Microsoft Graph?

So far I've tried:

```cs
// .Filter("CreatedDateTime gt 2016-12-18T14:13:30Z")
var news = client.Sites[Root]
    .SiteWithPath(path)
    .Lists[newsListId]
    .Items
    .Request()
    .Filter("CreatedDateTime gt 2016-12-18T14:13:30Z")
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
// => The request is malformed or incorrect.

// .OrderBy("CreatedDateTime desc")
var news = client.Sites[Root]
    .SiteWithPath(path)
    .Lists[newsListId]
    .Items
    .Request()
    .OrderBy("CreatedDateTime desc")
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
// => returns data but not in the requested order

//.Filter("year(CreatedDateTime) eq 2017")
var news = client.Sites[Root].SiteWithPath(path)
    .Lists[newsListId]
    .Items
    .Request()
    .Filter("year(CreatedDateTime) eq 2017")
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
// => ServiceException: Code: itemNotFound
//    Message: The resource could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The query parameter to limit your results to N results is $top.  See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters

I am not familiar with what SDK you are using, so I can't give you the exact code, but a sample of this in URL form would be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?$top=4
```

Maybe you could try:

```
.Top(N)
```

For filtering Sharepoint List items by date field, I haven't had success using the "createdDateTime" field available at /items/.  I *have* had success filtering the "Created" timestamp stored in the fields of the event.  Here is the format:
    .../items/?$filter=fields/Created lt '2017-12-22'

So looking at your samples above, maybe try:

```
.Filter("fields/Created lt '2017-12-22'")
```